# How to create multiple private DNS zones and then on each zone create multiple private DNS virtual link using for each loop in terraform azure

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-template-file, hashicorp

create multiple private DNS zones and then on each zone create multiple private DNS virtual link using for each loop in terraform azure.
and I am unable to create multiple virtual network links on each zone.

```
variable "privateDnsZones" {
  type = map(object({
    virtualNetworksID = list(string)
  }))
  default = {
    "privatelink.monitor.azure.com" = {
      virtualNetworksID = [
        "",
        ""
      ]
    },
    "privatelink.oms.opinsights.azure.com" = {
      virtualNetworksID = [
        "",
        ""
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "privateDnsZone" {
  for_each            = var.privateDnsZones
  name                = each.key
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.existing_RG.name
  tags                = var.resource_tags
  
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "privateDnsZone_link" {
    for_each =
  name                  = 
  resource_group_name   = 
  private_dns_zone_name = 
  virtual_network_id    = 
}
```

Comment: for each what? What are you looking over?

Comment: Try using `flatten`  and then use foreach for the vnet links on that flattend structure https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/flatten#flattening-nested-structures-for-for_each

Comment: Hi All,
I want to create multiple private DNS zones and then on each zone create multiple private DNS virtual link using for each loop in terraform azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Without having tested it**, it should work roughly like this:

```
locals {
  # flatten ensures that this local value is a flat list of objects, rather
  # than a list of lists of objects.
  zones_vnets = flatten([
    for zone_key, zone in var.privateDnsZones: [
      for vnetId in zone.virtualNetworksID : {
        zoneId = azurerm_private_dns_zone.privateDnsZone[zone_key].id
        vnetId = vnetId
      }
    ]
  ])
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "privateDnsZone_link" {
  for_each = {
    for zone in local.zones_vnets: "${zone.zoneId}.${zone.vnetId}" => zoneLink
  }
  name                  = each.key
  resource_group_name   = "foobar-rg"
  private_dns_zone_name = each.value.zoneId
  virtual_network_id    = each.value.vnetId
}
```

Comment: Error: Invalid reference
│
│   on main.tf line 72, in resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "privateDnsZone_link":       
│   72:     for zone in local.zones_vnets : "${zone.zoneId}.${zone.vnetId}" => zoneLink
│
│ A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.

Comment: glad to hear it @shubhampandey please accept the answer then (and upvote if you like :) )